# Hitting Mailchimp API with Axios, getting auth error. Could somebody give this a quick check?

Tags: mailchimp, axios, basic-authentication, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Pasted below is my code.  According to Mailchimp's [auth docs](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#authentication), it's  just basic auth.  Am I missing something?

```
router.post('/subscribe', function(req, res, next) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(`anystring:${mailchimpApiKey}`).toString('base64');
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed',
        timestamp_signup: Date.now()
    });

    axios.post(`${mailchimpApiUrl}/${mailchimpListId}/members`, {
        header: {
            'Authorization': auth,
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('response: ', res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    })

    res.send('hit subscribe endpoint!');
})
```

Comment: What does the error message say exactly? Also, is the above code client side?

Comment: having this issue now. was this ever resolved?